# Why is there a <p> tag where I didn't add it?

Tags: 7, blocks

I put the following code into the bock content box and set the input type to *Full HTML*; then I enabled it on page--front.tpl.php. When I viewed the HTML source, I
saw the `<a>` label contained a `<p>` tag.

```
  <ul>
      <li><a href="addons.html"><img class="floatleft" src="images/Panel-index03_108.jpg" /><p><strong>test</strong><br/>
      Fujia Chanpin 01</p></a></li>
       <li><a href="addons.html"><img class="floatleft" src="images/Panel-index03_108.jpg" /><p><strong>test</strong><br/>
      Fujia Chanpin 01</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="addons.html"><img class="floatleft" src="images/Panel-index03_108.jpg" /><p><strong>test</strong><br/>
      Fujia Chanpin 01</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="addons.html"><img class="floatleft" src="images/Panel-index03_108.jpg" /><p><strong>test/strong><br/>
      Fujia Chanpin 01</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="addons.html"><img class="floatleft" src="images/Panel-index03_108.jpg" /><p><strong>test</strong><br/>
      Fujia Chanpin 01</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="addons.html"><img class="floatleft" src="images/Panel-index03_108.jpg" /><p><strong>test</strong><br/>
      Fujia Chanpin 01</p></a></li>
      <li><a href="addons.html"><img class="floatleft" src="images/Panel-index03_108.jpg" /><p><strong>test</strong><br/>
      Fujia Chanpin 01</p></a></li>
    </ul>
```

For example, for the last list item, the output was the following.

```
<a href="addons.html"><img src="sites/all/themes/cpanel/images/cPanel-index03_108.jpg" class="floatleft"><p><strong>tsdet</strong><br>Fujia Chanpin 01</p><p></p></a>
```

Why is there a `<p>` tag where I didn't add it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For not getting the paragraph tags, you need to use an input format that does not include the *Lines and paragraphs break automatically* setting.

Check to see if *Convert line breaks into HTML* input format is enabled in admin/config/content/formats/full_html, and disable it. You can still add `<p>` and `<br>`, but Drupal will not add them automatically for every line break present in the text.

Comment: but my code needs paragraph and break tags.how do i do?

Comment: check to see if `Convert line breaks into HTML` is enabled `/admin/config/content/formats/full_html` and disable it. You can still use your own p and br, but Drupal will not convert it automatically.